# Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit won't start after I upgrade it, possible procesor problems?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I have a [HP 630](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3740644-3955548-5086782.html?dnr=1) with an i3 processor on which I run Windows 7 64 bit without any problems, I also dual booted Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit I believe, now I upgraded to 11.10 and the clean install doesn't have any apparent problems.

But first thing I update, my Ubuntu won't start it just goes into the purple screen, or more rarely a black screen with a blinking cursor, where it stays indefenetly. The only clue I could find was that when I entered recovery mode the last instruction which appeared on screen before it friezed was:

```
Booting Node 0,Processors #1
```

After I tried to install the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 11.10 from a USB stick It froze at exactly the same instruction and wouldn't let me install.

So it's a dual core problem, and maybe a BIOS problem, because it seems that it doesn't want to pass from one processor to another, I added to the grub command line `maxcpus=1` and it worked but I don't think it's healthy and it looks like hell.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: did it install a new kernel? can you try selecting an older kernel from the boot menu? Can you maybe attach a photo of the screen where we can read more?

Comment: please try Alt+Ctrl+F1 while purple screen: can You login in text mode?

Comment: I will try these suggestions but I don't think I can get a photo of the screen.

Comment: how about to make a photo with Your cell phone and send it to Your mail? :)

Comment: My phone doesn't have internet :) and I lost the cable but I'll see if I can get one of my colleagues to help.

Comment: Also there were a lot of updates so I can't say for sure but I don't think it installed a new kernell. I've been looking around as some people say I should install a older kernel but I've never done it before do you think it would help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will close this, a stop gap solution seems to be adding adding `maxcpus=1` but I think I will have to wait for the dev team to trully fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and now on 12.04 64 bit. My laptop is Lenovo G460 with Intel i3 350 processor. Try to update your BIOS. After updating mine, Ubuntu boot normally.